# Text field select all / place cursor with jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, selection

I have a text field in an edit form that is pre-populated with a value. I would like to give it the following behaviour:

- clicking inside the text field automatically selects the entire contents
- Clicking again inside the area deselects all the contents and places the cursor in the position where the user clicks

Here's my code:

```
// HTML
<input type="text" class="clickToSelect" value="myText" />

// jQuery
$(".clickToSelect").click(function(){
    $(this).select();
})
```

Now when the user clicks the field, all the text is selected but when they click a second time all the text is still selected. Any ideas how I can deselect the text on the second click and place the cursor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this?

```
    $(".clickToSelect").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("click-selectall")){
           $(this).addClass("click-selectall");
           $(this).select();
        }
    });

   $(".clickToSelect").blur(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("click-selectall");
    })
```

Comment: You're welcome, are you using this for some kind of search field?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".clickToSelect").one('click', function(){
    $(this).select();
})
```

[Working fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/BZgpn/)

**Update:** Multiple-Clicky-Worky:

```
$(".clickToSelect").click(function(){
    $this = $(this); // cache $(this) for better performance
    if (!$this.data('selected'))
    {
        $this.data('selected', true);
        $this.select();
    }
}).blur(function(){
    $this.data('selected', false);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMdCA/2/)

Comment: one() is nice, but will not work for the 2nd time (if the user click-click-click-away=then click). this last one will not work.

Comment: thanks for this - the solution provided by Mvision appears to work but yours is good too I think. Shame I can't accept two answers :(

Comment: Not to nit-pick but using data() attributes for something that in essence isn't really data kind of felt wrong, that's why I went with addClass in my answer

Comment: @Mvision I see where you're coming from - although one could as well argue that state is rather data than a class ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.slctText = function(start, end){

        var field = $J(this);
        if( field.createTextRange ){ 
            var selRange = field.createTextRange();
            selRange.collapse(true);
            selRange.moveStart("character", start);
            selRange.moveEnd("character", end);
            selRange.select();
        } else if( field.setSelectionRange ){ 
            field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else {
            if( field.selectionStart ){ 
                field.selectionStart = start;
                field.selectionEnd = end;
            }
        }
        return $(this);
}

$.fn.setCurPos = function(pos){

        $(this).slctText(pos,pos);
        $(this).focus();
}
```

Both are plugins .use it.